# Error when trying to write DataFrame to feather. Does feather support list columns?

Tags: python, r, pandas, list, feather

I'm working with both R and Python and I want to write one of my pandas DataFrames as a feather so I can work with it more easily in R.  However, when I try to write it as a feather, I get the following error:

```
ArrowInvalid: trying to convert NumPy type float64 but got float32
```

I doubled checked my column types and they are already float 64:

```
In[1]
df.dtypes

Out[1]
id         Object
cluster    int64
vector_x   float64
vector_y   float64
```

I get the same error regardless of using `feather.write_dataframe(df, "path/df.feather")` or `df.to_feather("path/df.feather")`.

I saw this on GitHub but didn't understand if it was related or not: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1345 and https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/1430

In the end, I can just save it as a csv and change the columns in R (or just do the whole analysis in Python), but I was hoping to use this.

*Edit 1:*

Still having the same issue despite the great advice below so updating what I've tried.

```
df[['vector_x', 'vector_y', 'cluster']] = df[['vector_x', 'vector_y', 'cluster']].astype(float)

df[['doc_id', 'text']] = df[['doc_id', 'text']].astype(str)

df[['doc_vector', 'doc_vectors_2d']] = df[['doc_vector', 'doc_vectors_2d']].astype(list)

df.dtypes

Out[1]:
doc_id           object
text             object
doc_vector       object
cluster          float64
doc_vectors_2d   object
vector_x         float64
vector_y         float64
dtype: object
```

*Edit 2:*

After much searching, it appears that the issue is that my cluster column is a list type made up of int64 integers.  So I guess the real quest is, does feather format support lists?

*Edit 3:*

Just to tie this in a bow, feather does not support nested data types like lists, at least not yet.

Comment: Did storing the lists as strings work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Luckly, I got the reason of my feather IO error here.
> - And I also got the solution for this problem, pandas.to_feather and read_feather are both based on pyarrow, and a column that contains lists as values is already support by pyarrow from 2019.

**Solution:**

```sh
pip install pyarrow==latest # my version is 1.0.0 and it work
```

Then, still use pd.to_feather("Filename") and read_feather.

Answer (score 6):

The problem in your case is the `id  Object` column. These are Python objects and they cannot represented in a language neutral format. This feather (actually the underlying Apache Arrow / `pyarrow`) is trying to guess the DataType of the `id` column. The guess is done on the first objects it sees in the column. These are `float64` numpy scalars. Later, you have `float32` scalars. Instead of coercing them to some type, Arrow is more strict with types and fails.

You should be able to work around this problem by ensuring that all columns have a non-object dtype with `df['id'] = df['id'].astype(float)`.

Comment: the id column is a string column--is there a type that I can convert it to that is compatible with arrow?

Comment: Yes, you can ensure that all object in the column are of the same Python type by using `df['id'].astype(str)`.

Comment: still having the same issue--looks like I'm not actually converting it from and object . . .  I updated the question with the code I've tried.

Comment: Try `df['id'] = df['id'].astype('string')`

Answer (score 6):

After much research, the simple answer is that feather does not support list (or other nested data type) columns.

Comment: here it says feather V2 supports list columns but in practice I noticed that it didn't... <https://ursalabs.org/blog/2020-feather-v2/>