# Converting excel to feather format with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, feather

I have a (daily growing) list of around 100 big excel files, which I analyse in Python. As I have to run several loops over all the files, my analysis are getting slower and slower. Therefore I'd like to convert all excel files into feather format (like once a week). Is there a clever way to do that? What I have tried so far:

```
path = r"filepath\*_name*.xlsx"
file_list = glob.glob(path)
for f in file_list:
    df = pd.read_excel(f, encoding='utf-8')
    df[['boola', 'boolb']] = dfa[['boola', 'boolb']].astype(int)
    pathname = f[:-5] + ".ftr"
    df.to_feather(pathname)
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
ArrowInvalid: ('Could not convert stringa with type str: tried to convert to boolean', "Conversion failed for column stringb with type object")
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to write an incompatible datatype to feather, have you tried explicitly casting the flagged column to an acceptable datatype? Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54369798/6121794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what solved my problem:

```
path = r"pathname\*_somename*.xlsx"
file_list = glob.glob(path)
for f in file_list:
    df = pd.read_excel(f, encoding='utf-8', decimal=',', thousands='.')
    for col in df.columns:
            w= (df[[col]].applymap(type) != df[[col]].iloc[0].apply(type)).any(axis=1)
            if len(df[w]) > 0:

                df[col] = df[col].astype(str)

            if df[col].dtype == list:
                df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
    pathname = f[:-4] + "ftr"
    df.to_feather(pathname)
df.head()
```

the `, decimal=',', thousands='.'` part was necessary because my input file was formatted in European standard, i.e. using comma as a decimal separator and a dot as thousands separator

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are getting this issue because the columns named `"stringa,stringb"` has some characters that feather cannot determine and he tried to convert to other types which returned error,
So my solution for the same problem I faced before was to actually convert the columns to string first and replace characters that caused the error
also:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path = 'c://examplepath//'
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path)]
for file in files:
     df = pd.read_excel(path+file)
     df['column'] = df['column'].astype(str)
     df['column'] = df['column'].replace('old charecter causing error','new charecter').astype(str)
     df.to_feather(path+file.split('.')[0]+'.feather')
```

N.B I don't think pd.read_excel needs the parameter encoding as per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).